# add custom property when writeValueAsString(object)

Tags: java, jackson

I have a id(Long) that js can not handle it. So when when I return id, I want to return another property id_str.

Just like :

`{"id":43777753494847488, "id_str":"43777753494847488"}`

I am using fastxml jackson  `writeValueAsString(object)` method.

What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please add your attempts to this questions - as this site is not a free "we do your (home)work" service. Beyond that: please turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks!

Comment: Why not just write the ID out as a String only, instead of writing it out as both a Long and a String?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fail to rewrite the JsonSerializer. Maybe it's to hard for me. So I modify the json string. here is the code:

```
public static String expandUserIDStr(String json) {
    String key = "user_id";
    String expandKey = "user_id_str";

    String r = "\"" + key + "\":(\\d+)[,]{0,1}";
    Pattern patter = Pattern.compile(r);
    Matcher matcher = patter.matcher(json);

    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String expandContent = "\"" + expandKey + "\":\"" + matcher.group(1) +"\"," + matcher.group(0);
        System.out.println(expandContent);
        matcher.appendReplacement(buffer, expandContent);
    }
    matcher.appendTail(buffer);

    return buffer.toString(); 
}
```